# Javascript Debugging - How to break on all unknown click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a jQuery mobile project and in order to close (most) popups I noticed I have to click twice in an area other than the popup.  In these cases it seems the first click removes the `#&ui-state=dialog` from the URL address bar while the second actually removes the popup.

I've checked for multiple includes of the same JS file and there is only one occurrence when viewing the source.  I'm refreshing the page directly so there is no chance of a second include of the JS file from navigation either.  As far as I can tell (and I'm pretty sure) there are not multiple custom click events bound to the button which triggers the pop-up (Maybe jQuery Mobile behind the scenes stuff, but not custom).

Is there a way for me to essentially listen for all click events as part of debugging and see what is going on with them?  I've added breaks to the custom JS code which opens the popup, and it only executes once.  But there is more going on and I don't know where it is coming from or how I can find it.

Comment: @MikeC suggestion worked and breaks on all events.  I added `if(cb = 'click'){` to filter out just click events but am not sure how to find what I'm looking for to aid in troubleshooting just yet. `console.log(this)` has a ton of information and seems to always output the window object.  I'll do some reading and if I can't figure it out I'll post another question.  I'll provide a link here if that is the case for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hijack the [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which would give you the option of knowing when an event is registered and even react *to* that event.

```
var oldAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(cb) {
  var customCB = function() {
    console.log('Hijacked event handler');
    return cb.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  console.log('Hijacked add event listener');
  return oldAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

If you want to capture *every* event, make sure you load in this code before any other additional code.

This works because [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/) inherits `addEventListener` from `EventTarget`. By overwriting that method on the prototype, this ensures that every `Element` will use your custom method when attaching an event listener.